# Download the latest version of python-pip using apt-get

Tags: apt, python, pip

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Python 2.7
- apt 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17 for amd64 compiled on Jun 13 2014 17:42:13

When I run `sudo apt-get install python-pip` It installs a a very old version.

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

This has caused me all sorts of problems as that version of pip has trouble locating many packages.

When I try to install the [latest version 1.5.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) via apt-get It wont locate it.

```
[$ sudo apt-get install python-pip=1.5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.5.6' for 'python-pip' was not found][2]
```

NOTE: I have previously run `apt-get update` and `apt-get update`

When I try to install pip by executing `sudo python get-pip.py` I get

```
$ python get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

I believe this is because of some issues with the Ubuntu VM proxy settings which I can get resolved later in the week.

Preferably I just want to install a recent version of pip via apt-get but I am open to any solution.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo pip install package-name
```

This works perfectly in Ubuntu 14.04,check in 12.04 otherwise upgrade the version and follow above steps.

Comment: These instructions worked for me to install Flask on 12.04.5 LTS, with the following changes: 0) Installed `software-properties-common` and `python-software-properties` to add a new PPA; 1) Switched python2.7 to the "deadsnakes" PPA, [per this Superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/942296/582181); 2) Ran the `apt-get purge` command for pip and Flask first, then rebooted; 3) Then, I followed the above instructions, and I was able to run Flask [per this Flask quickstart guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu official repositories don't have that new [a version of pip for 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-pip). And I couldn't find any PPAs. So `apt-get` won't be of much help. I think one way may be to install whatever version of `pip` is avalanche in the repositories and do `sudo pip install -U pip` - but this too will be affected by the proxy issue. One way out - upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: I have tried the 'sudo pip install -U pip' option already but as you  summarised it was not possible due to the proxy issue. I have no control over the version of Ubunto being used unfortunately

Comment: @Deepend how is proxy configured in your system? Are the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables set properly? Are special characters URL-encoded?